# AWS sam SES sendEmail results in InvalidClientTokenId (nodejs/lambda)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, token, amazon-ses

hopefully you can help me with this:

i am using AWS sam to build a AWS api-gateway with nodejs. everything works fine so far, but as i tried to send Emails through AWS SES i am getting following error:

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"InvalidClientTokenId","errorMessage":"The security token included in the request is invalid.","code":"InvalidClientTokenId","message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."
```

i am using following code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const SESConfig = {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_SES,
        secretAccesskey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_SES,
        apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION
      };

var params = {
        Destination: {
         ToAddresses: [
          userDataObject.email
         ]
        }, 
        Message: {
         Body: {
          Html: {
           Charset: "UTF-8", 
           Data: "This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class=\"ulink\" href=\"http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide\" target=\"_blank\">Amazon SES Developer Guide</a>."
          }, 
          Text: {
           Charset: "UTF-8", 
           Data: "This is the message body in text format."
          }
         }, 
         Subject: {
          Charset: "UTF-8", 
          Data: "Test email"
         }
        }, 
        ReplyToAddresses: [
        ], 
        ReturnPath: "", 
        ReturnPathArn: "", 
        Source: "sender@example.com", 
        SourceArn: ""
       };

 await new AWS.SES(SESConfig).sendEmail(params).promise().then((response) => {
         console.log(response);
       })
```

- i double checked, that the tokens for the IAM user are fine, and contain no special characters.
- i also checked, that the SES account is not in sandbox mode.
- i verified that the variables in SESConfig are actually readable and contain the required data.
- i tried to use full SES Access for the users policy. i also tried with full admin
  privileges
- aws-sdk generally works in this project: i can upload data to s3 for example
- sending email through smtp with nodemailer will probably work, but i didn't tried that because i really want to try out the aws-sdk

i would be very glad if someone could point out if im doing something wrong in general or if someone has an idea of what i could try to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

For everyone having the same problem, this is how i solved the issue:

1. removing the accessKeyId and secretAccesskey from the function
2. removing the accessKeyId and secretAccesskey from my .gitlab-ci.yml
3. removing the accessKeyId and secretAccesskey from the sam template.yaml
4. going to Identity and Access Management (IAM) in the aws console
5. heading to roles
6. searching for the role of the lambda function (which is typically the arn of the lambda function)
7. attaching the right ses policy. you can also create a new one if you like. for an example read further

ses policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ses:SendEmail",
            "ses:SendRawEmail"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

updated and working code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const ses = new AWS.SES({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });
      
      const params = {
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: [userDataObject.email],
        },
        Message: {
          Body: {
            Text: { Data: "Test" },
          },
    
          Subject: { Data: "Test Email" },
        },
        Source: "example@example.com",
      };
     
      await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
```

i learned three things from this:

1. the aws documentation is quite good: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/
2. setting roles for lambda functions through the aws IAM console is kind of elegant compared to creating a new IAM user and placing the access information (accessKey, etc.) into the deploying process
3. i should read the aws documentation more carefully before posting to stackoverflow